# Use values of select into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't know if the title of the question is clear enough but I have this situation:

```
TABLE ID, VALUE_1, VALUE_2
       1, HORSE  , 500
       1, DOG    , 400
       1, DUCK   , 300
       2, HORSE  , 500
       2, DOG    , 400
       2, DUCK   , 300
```

I Want to see those values like

```
ID HORSE DOG DUCK
1    500 400 300
2    500 400 300
```

Comment: 1. What is your Oracle version? In Oracle 11.1 or higher, you can use the `PIVOT` operator, which does the same thing as conditional aggregation, but the syntax is clearer (and perhaps the code behind it is optimized too). 2. Are `HORSE`, `DOG` and `DUCK` the only values you are interested in? If not, is the full list known in advance? If it isn't then the problem is much harder - best to address it in your reporting tool, not in a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `condititonal aggregation`

```
select id,
       max(case when value_1 = 'HORSE' then value_2 end ) as horse,
       max(case when value_1 = 'DOG' then value_2 end ) as dog,
       max(case when value_1 = 'DUCK' then value_2 end ) as duck
  from tab
 group by id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62a598a43b1a81804a84a371dc07c442)</kbd>

Comment: @MatheusCiaramella prego.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when value_1 = 'HORSE' then value_2 end) as horse,
       sum(case when value_1 = 'DOG' then value_2 end) as dog,
       sum(case when value_1 = 'DUCK' then value_2 end) as duck
from t
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Worked just fine as well! Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  ID,
  max(case when value_1 = 'HORSE' THEN value_2 end) HORSE,
  max(case when value_1 = 'DOG' THEN value_2 end) DOG,
  max(case when value_1 = 'DUCK' THEN value_2 end) DUCK
from tablename
group by ID
```

Comment: Worked just fine as well! Thank you @forpas

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11.1 and higher, you can use the `PIVOT` operator. Assuming the table name is `T`:

```
select id, horse, dog, duck
from   t
pivot  (min(value_2) 
        for value_1 in ('HORSE' as horse, 'DOG' as dog, 'DUCK' as duck))
order  by id
;
```

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, the same can be achieved with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` (and we don't need aggregation anymore):

```
select id, horse, dog, duck
from   t
match_recognize(
  partition by id
  measures  horse.value_2 as horse,
            dog.value_2   as dog,
            duck.value_2  as duck
  pattern   ( (horse|dog|duck)* )
  define    horse as value_1 = 'HORSE', dog as value_1 = 'DOG', 
             duck as value_1 = 'DUCK'
);
```

Comment: Hi @mathguy, I tried the first one with pivot, wich I found really interesting but tricky... Didn't worked for the purpose I wanted, but thank you anyway!